# how to create a Backdoor (add a login) to ephemeral images

Tags: maas

Can anyone tell me, if this is a script that needs to be created or are these commands that need to be entered?

Now, I do know that some are commands. I have no idea what the rest are. And do I enter these from the MaaS server?

```
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes bzr             
bzr branch lp:~maas-maintainers/maas/backdoor-image backdoor-image    

imgs=$(echo /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/*/*/*/*/*/root-image)
for img in $imgs; do
    [ -f "$img.dist" ] || cp -a --sparse=always $img $img.dist
done    

for img in $imgs; do
    sudo ./backdoor-image/backdoor-image -v --user=backdoor --password-auth --password=ubuntu $img
done
```

Answer (score 0):

That is a shell script, and it needs to be run on the machine which holds the images in `/var/lib/maas/boot-resources`. Just save the whole script in a file like `mk-backdoor.sh`, add `#!/bin/bash` as first line, `chmod +x mk-backdoor.sh` and then execute it, possibly using `sudo`, like `sudo ./mk-backdoor.sh`. Be sure to update the values for username and password first.

**What the commands are doing**

Install bzr without user interaction:

```
sudo apt-get install --assume-yes bzr
```

Checks out the backdoor-image code:

```
bzr branch lp:~maas-maintainers/maas/backdoor-image backdoor-image
```

Collects the paths of all images in the boot-resources
folder. The * stuff is more or less telling the command
to go a certain number of folders deep, and look for a
file called root-image:

```
imgs=$(echo /var/lib/maas/boot-resources/*/*/*/*/*/root-image)
```

This make copies of the images, if they didn't exist yet:

```
for img in $imgs; do
    [ -f "$img.dist" ] || cp -a --sparse=always $img $img.dist
done
```

This creates the backdoor user with username "backdoor"
and password="ubuntu" on each image:

```
for img in $imgs; do
    sudo ./backdoor-image/backdoor-image -v --user=backdoor --password-auth --password=ubuntu $img
done
```

Comment: how do you log in.

Comment: Do you need to recommission ?

Comment: No, you do not need to recommission, you login on the console of the system.